# run on click function at the click of a button or another

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have something like:

```
$('#friendRequests').on('click', '.acceptFriendRequest', function (event) {
 // code here
}
```

How could I make the click of `.denyFriendRequest` to run that same function above, and to know which button was clicked (to decide whether to accept or deny the request in my backend)

Thank you

Comment: If using SO has solved your problem, it's generally accepted good practice for you to 'accept' the answer you felt helped you the most, was the most appropriate or in the case of a tie, came first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to bind event to multiple elements and use `this`, $(this) or `this.target`  to refer to current element.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H2fgS/1/)**

```
$('#friendRequests').on('click', '.acceptFriendRequest, .denyFriendRequest', function (event) {    
     alert(this.className);
     //alert($(this).attr('class');
     //alert(event.target.className);
});
```

If you expect the element to have multiple classes and you need if one of classes would be .acceptFriendRequest or .denyFriendRequest then you can use [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
$('#friendRequests').on('click', '.acceptFriendRequest, .denyFriendRequest', function (event) {    
   if($this).hasClass('acceptFriendRequest')
   {

   }
   if($this).hasClass('denyFriendRequest')
   {

   }
});
```

Comment: using `$(this).hasClass('. acceptFriendRequest')` might work better than `className` in case other classes end up being applied to those elements.

Answer (score 1):

try using jquery [hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

```
$('#friendRequests').on('click', function (event) {

  if ($(this).hasClass("acceptFriendRequest")) {
    //
  } else if ($(this).hasClass("denyFriendRequest")) {
    //
  } else {
    //
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('#friendRequests').on('click', '[class$="FriendRequest"]', function (event) {
  console.log(event.target.className);
}
```